# Don't print comment at end of line in makefile

Tags: make

I'd like to add comments at the end of lines in my makefiles.

```
rule:
    echo 1 # Print 1
```

However, when running this makefile, the comment also gets printed in the command-line.

```
$ make rule
echo 1 # Print 1
1
```

But I'd like the comment (but not the command) to be hidden. Is there a way to have comments at the ends of lines in makefiles that are not printed? (I'm aware that you can hide a comment by prefixing it with a `@`, but that only works if the whole line is a comment and not at the end of lines.)

Comment: I'm not sure if the issue here is a visual issue... You could execute `make rule | sed 's/#.*$//'` and remove everything that's after `#`.

Comment: @raylight: Interesting idea, but that would be cumbersome to type in everytime I want to run make.

Comment: `@` stops the command line from being printed along with the output of the command. It is not used to hide comments. Could you possibly clarify whether you only want to hide the comment, or the whole command.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Edited! I want the command shown, but the comment hidden.

Comment: I'd agree with [Marcus Müller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740220/dont-print-comment-at-end-of-line-in-makefile#comment1405827_740226) that needing comments in this way infers your makefile is too complex. Consider moving long lists of actions into their own shell script files which can be commented more easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That `# print 1` is not a comment for `make`, the whole `echo 1 # print 1` line (without the leading TAB) is passed to the shell (by executing `$(SHELL)` with `-c` and *`that-line`* as extra arguments), and the shell interprets it as a comment in that context. In other contexts, such as in a `echo "foo # bar"` or with `$(SHELL)`s that don't treat `#` as comment leader, it won't. In any case, unless that's disabled with `@` or `.SILENT`, `make` prints the code passed to the shell.

A *make* comment inside a Makefile recipe has to have the `#` as the very first character of the line:

```
rule:
# print 1:
    echo 1
```

Or as comment lines can also be continued with a backslash:

```
rule:
#\
    # print 1:
    echo 1
```

You could do:

```
rule:
    @# print 1:
    echo 1
```

That does call one shell for each line of that recipe. For that first line that's an inline shell script with only one *shell* comment, the `@` skips the *echoing* of that shell code by `make` and is not part of the code passed to the shell.

See [`info make 'comments, in recipe'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html#index-comments_002c-in-recipes) on GNU system (for the GNU implementation of `make`) for details

> A comment in a recipe is not a make comment; it will be passed to the shell as-is. Whether the shell treats it as a comment or not depends on your shell.

And more generally [`info make comments`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Contents.html#index-comments_002c-in-makefile) about comments in Makefile's.

---

Now, what you could do instead is disable `make`'s echoing altogether with a `.SILENT` rule and let the shell do the echoing itself with its `xtrace` option:

```
SHELL = sh -o xtrace
export PS4 =
.SILENT: rule

rule:
    echo 1 # print 1
```

Comment: Yes, but this becomes very verbose when you want to comment multiple lines, hence why I want them at the ends of the lines.

Comment: @nijoakim, then you can't `#` does not introduce a comment in makefile recipes so it will be passed to the shell, and either you use `@` to hide that whole thing or the shell comment will be printed along with the rest of the shell code.

Comment: I'll also say that most of the time, complex Makefiles are generated by some automated configure-and-build system. If you need to add comments to your Makefiles, it **might** (really not a **must**) be the case where you'd be better off by taking a step back, look at what you're doing with a Makefile, and wonder whether you really *want* to be writing whatever you're writing as a Makefile, or whether using some Makefile generator (cmake, auto\*, meson…) or just plain shell scripts aren't the way to go.

Comment: (note that while I really love the *idea* of what "make" does – automatically manage builds based on explicit and implicit dependencies between fragments and offer an interface to build specific targets – I consider the implementation `make` to be quite a bad one. The syntax, as you notice here, is an inflexible design from 1976, and the language design overall reeks of bad decisions, which make correct Makefile programming hard. Which is a lot of the reason why the Makefile generators are such hostile beasts, at times. A lot of their functionality could well be done in a `make`-equivalent.)